# Android HTTP post with {"key" => JSON}

Tags: java, android, json

I've been using lots of HTTP posts in my apps recently and I've always been using this template:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(server);
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name","John"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age",13+""));
...
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

And on the server's PHP script:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
...
```

This has always worked perfectly. However, recently I got a request that the data should actually be a JSON itself which would contain all those key-value pairs.

To be more explicit, the PHP script has been written to do this:

```
$json = $_POST['data'];
$name = $json['name'];
$age = $json['age'];
...
```

While this is an awkwardly simple modification, I can't seem to make it work in the Android code, i.e. I can't find the correct way to add the JSON to the HTTP data.

I'm doing this:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("name", "John");
json.put("age", 13+"");
...
```

But what to do next?? How can I add this JSON to the HTTP with the key "data"?

I've tried this:

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", json.toString()));
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

But I'm not sure it's the right way to do it and also the server's response is signalling an error.

How should I do it? How should I GENERALLY add a JSONObject with a key, or even a JSONArray?

Thanks!

EDIT: Please don't send me to other SO links, I've looked and none is answering straight to my point.

Answer (score 1):

Generally write json:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidJSON/article.html#androidjson_write

For your task, you don't need to put your json into a list. Just do

```
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(json.toString())); 
//or else use this
httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8));
```

EDIT:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("name", "John");
json.put("age", 13+"");
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
data.put("data", json.toString());
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data.toString()));
```

Comment: I already said that answers already on SO don't help me, and your answer is the same with what I can find around here. I NEED to somehow set the "data" key for the JSON.